# Visual Basic 2008 - Interaction with database (reading / writing to database tables and fields)

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, database-connection

Using Visual Basic 2008 express, I would like to access a database with 2 tables,
one table (useraccounts) which has Users and Password and ID, and the other table which has information (linktable)

Basically I would like to do a login form which reads from the table useraccounts and be able to create new users which will write into the database.
Another is that I have a form with a number of links which I would like to store in the table 'linktable' and it basically just gets the links from the table and straight to the form where it is used.
I have tried using access or the .mdf files that visual basic has but I have been unable to find an answer for either.

**I wouldnt mind using either access or the .mdf file for the database, I would just like it to work**

Overall I am trying to get:

- Login form which reads from database table 'useraccounts' and has a new user feature
- Just a form that can read / write to the database once the save button is clicked

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try following article to get you started

[CRUD with ADO.NET, DAL and Stored Procedures](http://srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/dotnet/adonetcrud2.aspx)